# Concatenating two memory buffers without memcpy

Tags: c, memory-management

In C I have a function foo(char *) that accepts a memory pointer.
in the caller, I have two different memory buffers,
which I need to concatenate so I can pass one pointer foo().
Is there a way for me to do that without actually copying one buffer 
to the end of the other buffer and without changing foo() itself?
I.e make the two buffers appear as one virtual continuous buffer to foo()

I need this for performance reasons. an O(n) solution (where n is one of the buffers length)
is not acceptable for my case.
Also, a Linux specific solution is fine, if it helps.

Thanks.
Nir

Comment: Are you trying to make these memory buffers contiguous in the kernel virtual address space or the user virtual address space? Are they page aligned? Is the length of the first buffer a multiple of the page size?

Comment: Also, is the virtual address space after the end of the first buffer unallocated? Can you apply J.F. Sebastian's answer to virtual address space allocations to make this possible?

Comment: And finally, is there a break-even point where calling ioremap() is faster than just copying the buffer?

Comment: where? In the kernel address space. page aligned? no. multiple? I don't think so. would it help if they were?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question seems to ask whether it is possible to concatenate the contents of two buffers (A and B) with the following constraints:

- You can't copy the contents of A or B.
- You can't change the address of A.
- The operation must have a worst case complexity < O(n).
- Presumably the address of B is such that A and B are not already concatenated. (As J.F. Sebastian pointed out in his answer, if you can allocate both A and B contiguously in the first place, you're done. But this seems like a degenerate case.)
- You must be able to do this from a Linux kernel driver (see comment under Jerome's answer).
- Neither A nor B is page aligned (see comment under original question).
- Neither A nor B is a multiple of the page size (see comment under original question).

Given all that, my answer is no: it is not possible.

Yes, an OS kernel can use the CPU's MMU (memory management unit, on architectures that have one) to remap memory in either the kernel virtual address space or the user virtual address space. Allocate a contiguous chunk of virtual address space, then remap A and B into that buffer by modifying the page table entries for the chunk of virtual address space to point to the physical addresses of A and B.

This doesn't change the virtual address of A per se (since the old virtual address is still valid), but it does require you to access it through a different virtual address. This may be a problem.

The granularity of this remapping on today's typical CPU architectures is based on the page size(s), and since A and B are not page aligned nor are they a multiple of the page size, you will not be able to make them completely line up. This is definitely a problem.

Remapping N bytes requires modifying at least one page table entry for every M bytes, where M is the page size. This means that the remapping operation has a computational complexity of O(n) anyway. Other operations such as allocating more physical pages for page tables, flushing caches and TLBs, etc. would have additional performance implications.

Also, I'm wondering if the goal of this question somehow involves DMA (direct memory access). When performing DMA with an archaic device that requires contiguous memory, no amount of remapping is going to help unless you have an IOMMU at your disposal. And a modern device that can do scatter-gather DMA wouldn't require contiguous buffers in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. much appreciated. I learned a lot by reading and trying to understand what you said. It made me realize that I could make my constraints a bit easier and try to find other ways to satisfy my needs.

Comment: what if A and B _are_ page-aligned and multiples of page size?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a way.

Allocate memory for the buffers in a such way that they are adjacent in memory.

Example:

```
char* a = malloc(a_size + b_size);
char* b = a + a_size;
```

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I make no assumptions on the content of the `a` and `b` buffers. If `a` is a C-string then `a_size = a_len + 1`.

Comment: But if `foo(char* c)` expects a C-string then the above trick won't work anyway (due to '\0' in the middle of `c`).

Comment: Dude, LOVE the moniker :) Do you get many "Gooooood evening J.F." salutations?

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for the shortness of the answer, but No, you can't.

As you've said yourself, you either need to

- Allocate one large buffer, and copy
  the seperate buffers to this or
- Change foo, to take multipe pointers.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no general solution for this.

Your only hope is if the two memory regions you want to concatenate already are directly after each other in the memory address space.

Comment: Even if the two buffers are adjacent, it probably wouldn't work since the buffers are most likely null-terminated (since the method doesn't take a length param).

Comment: And that hope really is no hope, it's not going to happen unless under very specific circumstances, and if Nir could control those, he wouldn't be asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such solution, unless you have knowledge about how memory allocator works, combined with pure luck.

Why do you allocate two buffers when you know that you'll need one afterwards?  And how big are the buffers?  Why are you avoiding copying?  Have you measured that that would be a bottleneck?

Comment: Good questions..
My problem is that the string are part of frequent network packets which aren't reasonably bounded in size. Also, I can't/don't want to alter the code that allocates them. Another thing which I haven't mentioned is that I don't have a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding another layer of indirection.  It'd require you to rewrite foo to take an array of `char *`s, and to be able to handle the boundary condition between strings.

```
void foo(char **, int nstrings)
{ 
}
```

Then concatenating the strings is just a matter of creating a pointer array:

```
char *strings[2] = { string1, string2 };
foo (strings, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible  to modify `foo()` to take some sort of descriptor that describes a list of memory locations to act on (like a pointer to an array of structs with pointer/length pairs)?

That way there is no need for an O(N) copy operation.

If it's possible, that seems to be the only reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

look at using realloc.  Once you get a second buffer you can call realloc to increase the size of the first buffer.  My experience with Mac OS is that this is highly optimized.

Answer (score -1):

The following is a quite dirty solution, but maybe the only one in your case. And it will not work in all the cases (furthermore it is not predictable).

You can try to use `mmap`. When invoking mmap, you give it an address. mmap will try to allocate memory at the address you gave to it.

This solution is maybe the best you can have. You will only have to copy one `char[]`, and none both.

You maybe would have to erase the `\0` character at the end of the first.

And you can use the `MAP_FIXED` flag: if the mmap can not use the address, it will not allocate any memory space and return an error.

eg.

```
char a[20];
char b[20];

mmap(a + 20, 20, PROT_WRITE, MAP_FIXED, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thought about that. The problem is I'm inside the linux kernel.
I'm new to kernel programming but, I think you can't use mmap inside the kernel. Maybe there's another kernel way for doing it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that trying to map bytes from stdin into the middle of the stack is guaranteed to fail. (What's more, the address is probably not page aligned.)

Comment: @Nir, that information would have been really useful when reading the question.

Comment: The assumption he uses malloc could be done. And there are maybe not other solution, so at least this is one. This solution is the closest for what he wants (but not in kernel).